# Editing a Virtual Arsenal in Arma 3 with SQF

Tags: sqf

not sure if I can ask a question like this on Stack Over flow but basically in Arma 3 im currently editing a scenario called Antistasi, I want to remove some weapons from the virtual arsenal, i've got the variable name, but I have tried all the following and it is not removing the desired item.

```
[ caja, ["arifle_MXM_F"], true ] call BIS_fnc_removeVirtualItemCargo;
[ caja, ["arifle_MXM_F"], true ] call BIS_fnc_removeVirtualWeaponCargo;
```

Some help would be appreciated

Edit - It defiantly is the correct Variable as I can move it around with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t say how you created the arsenal.  I always favour scripting so the following will create a virtual arsenal with all weapons in a weapon crate named **CRATE_1**:

```
["AmmoboxInit", [CRATE_1, true]] call BIS_fnc_arsenal;
```

If you want to put this code in the ‘Object:Init’ field of the crate in the Eden editor then you need to use:

```
noUse = ["AmmoboxInit", [this, true]] call BIS_fnc_arsenal;
```

**noUse** is unimportant but a variable is required.

However if you do that the **BIS_fnc_removeVirtualWeaponCargo** function to remove weapons does not work.  I believe there is a bug when you create a virtual weapon crate with all weapons.  I get a half hidden error message when I open the arsenal "BIS_fnc_baseWeapon Class '%All' not found in CfgWeapons".

You can create an empty arsenal and add weapons to it.  Those can be removed but I am guessing that is not what you want to do. The following code works:

```
["AmmoboxInit", [CRATE_1, false]] call BIS_fnc_arsenal;

[ CRATE_1, ["SMG_03_black", "arifle_MX_GL_F"], true ] call BIS_fnc_addVirtualWeaponCargo;
[ CRATE_1, ["SMG_03_black"], true ] call BIS_fnc_removeVirtualWeaponCargo;
```

I favour creating empty virtual arsenals and specifying the equipment I want in the arsenal.  Bear in mind there are 4 functions for adding items to a virtual arsenal:

```
BIS_fnc_addVirtualWeaponCargo;
BIS_fnc_addVirtualMagazineCargo;
BIS_fnc_addVirtualItemCargo;
BIS_fnc_addVirtualBackpackCargo;
```

I offer a final warning if you are trying to limit weapons usable by players.  The virtual arsenal will always show a weapon or equipment a player currently has on his character.  In addition a player can load a loadout they previously saved that may have weapons and equipment you do not want them to have.

Comment: You can remove their previous kit on joining the server as a filtering mechanism can't you? Virtual arsenal will only reflect the current loadout